# How to make to combo box display numbers from 0 to a number in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this empty combo box which I would like to fill with numbers from 0 to x. x is a value in a table.

I know almost nothing about VBA so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO can help you with code you've written but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Google how to fill a combo box in access vba with a loop

Answer (score 2):

When you add the combobox to the form make sure you select I will type in the values that I want radiobutton.

- From the Devolper Tab change the view to Design View
- Right click the blank space below the form and click Properties
- The Properties Sheet should have Form selected in the Selection Type Combo near the top
- Click the Event Tab
- Select the On Load event and click the ellipse [...] button
- Choose Code Builder

You can use DLookup, DMax, Or DMin to retrieve the your values from the a query or table.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxNumber As Long
    maxNumber = DLookup("[StockLevel]", "InventoryTable", "[SKU] = 'HSC0424PP'")
    For i = 0 To maxNumber
        Combo4.AddItem i
    Next
End Sub
```